# Update Assignment in Project Online using JSOM

Tags: jsom, ms-project, project-online

I noticed that Assignments and Tasks are 2 different concepts in Project Online. For me to send the task to the approval center i need to update the Assignments using JSOM.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this. I have posted the solution in another post.

URL: [send the task to approval center using JSOM Project Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200091/send-the-task-to-approval-center-using-jsom-project-online)

Reference link for project online solutions:
[dsouzajoel.com](http://dsouzajoel.com)